# What is the best way to provide a server-side property to a JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a `system.properties` file with things like system version and build type that I'd like to show on my index.jsp pages (I have several in a suite of dashboards). What is the best way to provide those properties to my JSPs?

I'm currently reading the properties file directly from the JSPs, but that's cumbersome because it's several lines of code and it has to be duplicated across all of my JSPs. I did abstract that code out into its own JSP that I then include on my other JSPs, but that still feels cumbersome.

Ideally, I'd like to do the following from any page:

`<body data-build-type='${buildType}' data-system-version='${systemVersion}'>`

That could mean that I use a servlet or a servlet-filter, but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Well a JSP *is* a servlet of sorts. But since it is made of declarative markup and adding non-trivial code statements to it is a practice generally frowned upon, you could indeed add a centralized (stateless) service to retrieve that information from all your JSPs in the form of a servlet that they could access. I personally can't see how a servlet filter would be scoped in this however.

Comment: Another option is to create a PropertiesTag - which you can then include in your JSPs to render server properties.

Comment: @donlys - Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a WebListener that implements ServletContextListener.
So on deployment you could read the system properties and set them as attributes.
Either separately or in a map.

**system.properties**:

Lets say you have a file `system.properties` with content:

```
buildType=myType
systemVersion=v55
```

**WebListener**:

The WebListener could be something like:

```
package testingThings.properties;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Properties;  
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

@WebListener
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    public ContextListener() {}
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {}

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        InputStream stream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("testingThings/properties/system.properties");
        Properties props = new Properties();

        try {
            props.load(stream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for (final String name : props.stringPropertyNames()) {
            map.put(name, props.getProperty(name));
        }

        sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("system", map);
    }
}
```

**JSP:**

In a JSP you can iterate through the `system` attribute like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head><title>access map of system properties</title></head>
<body>
    <h3>access map of system properties</h3>
    <table>
        <c:forEach items="${system}" var="property">
            <tr>
                <td>${property.key}:</td>
                <td>${property.value}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        <tr>
    </table>

    <h3>directly access of map properties</h3>
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>buildType:</td>
                <td>${system.buildType}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>systemVersion:</td>
                <td>${system.systemVersion}</td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

If the system properties are changing dynamically,
you can update them, directly in the context attribute (parallel to the system.properties file)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I have a Maven project. Can you explain our point me to an explanation on where to place the WebListener java file?

Comment: For this example, i put listener and properties file in the same package `testingThings.properties`. You can separated them, however you want. The listener goes somewhere in your `src` folder `src/main/java`. If you add the annotation `@WebListener` in front of the class definition, it will be recognized on deployment/synchronization.

Comment: I am glad, i could help. Don't forget to accept the answer and upvote

Answer (score 0):

Create a JSP custom tag. For example:

```
public class HelloWorld extends TagSupport
{
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException
    {
        try
        {
            JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)pageContext.getResponse();
            out.write("Hello world!"); <!-- your property 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {   
            throw new JspException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return EVAL_PAGE;
    }
}
        <!-- a tab library descriptor -->
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/JSP/TagLibraryDescriptor">
  <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
  <jsp-version>1.2</jsp-version>
  <short-name>Simple Tags</short-name>

  <tag>
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <tag-class>HelloWorld</tag-class>
    <body-content>empty</body-content>
  </tag>
</taglib>
```

Using it in your JSP:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <hw:HelloWorld />
  </body>
</html>
```

Hello World is just an example - you can have all of your attributes (system properties) defined in your tag and get those in the JSP this way. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html